# JavaFX How to disable maximization on Mac OS?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

How can I disable maximization? For Windows works: `stage.setResizable(false);`
but for Mac do not work even this:

```
stage.maximizedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue)
                stage.setMaximized(false);
        });
```

BTW. I don't want to disable all the buttons: Minimze, Maximize. I just want to disable maximize function